# Настройка роутера на линуксе

Tags: linux, роутер, torrent

Есть подопытный Asus WL500g, работает на Linux version 2.4.37.11, как написано в настройках роутера. Команды по типу echo и ls работают. Попытался поставить rtorrent командой sudo apt-get install rtorrent, но sudo не работает - говорит -sh: sudo: not found. Вопрос: есть ли другой способ сделать торрент сервер на роутере без перепрошивки? P.S. в стандартных настройках торрента нет

Comment: думаю, что если решите проблему с sudo, у Вас будет проблема с apt-get. apt-get - это дебиановское решение и далеко не факт, что на этом роутере также дебиан.

Comment: Ставьте OpenWRT.

Answer (score 1):

Если говорит, что

```
-sh: sudo: not found
```

то (скорее всего) означает, что установлена чрезвычайно урезанная версия линуха, в которой нет ничего, что не нужно непосредственно для работы роутера. Попробуйте, с помощью команды *ls* посмотреть содержимое каталогов */bin* и */usr/bin*. Если там есть что-то для работы с интернетом (*ftp, scp, wget...*) тогда можно попытаться скачать бинарники и руками разложить их по нужным директориям.

Comment: Там есть busybox, а значит есть tftp. Надо попробовать

Comment: Хмм, wget https://github.com/downloads/libevent/libevent/libevent-2.0.18-stable.tar.gz не работает. Говорит wget: not an http or ftp url: https://github.com/downloads/libevent/libevent/libevent-2.0.18-stable.tar.gz

Comment: А busybox у вас - где? А то ведь он используется, зачастую, на этапе ДО загрузки ОС. Там сеть ещё не настроена.

Comment: А вот это хороший вопрос. Я увидел в листинге ls /bin, там был busybox

Comment: @ЕгорКоновалов " not an http or ftp url:" - я прверил эту ссылку у себя *wget* скачал архив нормально. Но, м.б. у Вас там какая-то очень старая версия *wget* которая требует **явного** указания типа  протокола? Попробуйте дописать впереди *https://*

Comment: @ЕгорКоновалов - а может быть дело в том, что этот URL просто недоступен? Посмотрите *ifconfig* - у Вас сеть вообще - есть? А если естьЮ то что скажет *ping github.com* ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109638/discussion-between---and-sergey).